# Links to an exisiting Page are now redirecting to a draft page?

Tags: redirect

I have a page that has been working fine for a while now.
However I'm looking to replace it in the not to distant future. (testing conversions)

I though the correct process for this would be to create a draft of the new page ready to swap.

Then once I'm ready to change. Unpublish the exisiting page. 
Rename the URL/slug to something like/page1old
then publish the new page with the old pages slug/url.

However somehow in attempting to set this up, something weird has happened and I'm getting a autoredirection occurring.

All links pointing to the old page are now redirecting to the draft page on my live site? I'm hovering over the links and the URL is right www.mysite.com/page1
however when I click on the link it redirects to www.mysite.com/page2

Why has it autoredirected? 
How is it possible to redirect to a draft page that has not be published?

Very bizarre?

Answer (score 1):

Looks to be Redirection plugin issue. Think it's been abandoned by its creator as it's messed up a few of my sites.

Comment: I've had issues with this plugin as well. It tries to be helpful with things like renamed posts, but I've been left scratching my head at strange redirects more than once.

Comment: Please come back later and mark your answer as accepted so others will know what the problem was (I know you can't now - just wanted to make sure you remember to after the required time delay). Thanks!

Comment: *@Adam* - What @tnorthcutt said.  Also, I'll confirm that a user of one of my plugins blamed my plugin when Redirection plugin caused problems.