# Slug is redirecting to 404

Tags: pages, redirect, slug

I had a page called Recipes.  I changed it to Recipes_old and changed the slug so I could create a new Recipes page.  When I created the new Recipes page the slug was properly defined as /recipes/ but I can't get to the page, WordPress is redirecting all requests to /recipes_old/

How do I remove the redirect?  I have at this point deleted Recipes_old and Recipes.  Still the slug is being redirected.

Answer (score 3):

This was caused by the Redirection plugin. Apparently it is trying to help by setting up redirects when you change the slugs for pages/posts.  You have to click on "Groups" at the top of the Redirection plugin settings and then choose "Modified posts" to see the redirection that was automatically created to point from the old slug to the new one.  Unfortunately these are not cleaned up when pages/posts are deleted.

Comment: Redirection [strikes again](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2655/links-to-an-exisiting-page-are-now-redirecting-to-a-draft-page/2656#2656)!